# Grant privileges to current user in procedure

Tags: oracle12c

I have a procedure like that:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE CREATE_TABLE_TEST
(I_REPORTID IN number,) 
IS 
  pDatTable varchar2(50);
  pDefTable varchar2(50);
  pApplication APPLICATION%Rowtype;
  cursor pCursor is select * from reportdesc where reportid = I_REPORTID;
BEGIN
select ap.* into pApplication from APPLICATION ap inner join reportgroups rpg on ap.APPID = rpg.APPID 
  inner join reports rp on rpg.GROUPID = rp.GROUPID  where  rp.ID = i_reportid;
  select DATTABLE into pDatTable from reports where id=I_REPORTID;

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = '||pApplication.appuser;
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'grant SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE on '||pApplication.appuser||'.'|| pDatTable||' to QT' ;
END CREATE_TABLE_TEST;
```

When I login as user QT and execute the procedure, it shows the error:

```
ORA-01749: you may not GRANT/REVOKE privileges to/from yourself
ORA-06512: at "QT.CREATE_TABLE_TEST", line 21
```

How can I fix it? thanks.

Update: The scenario is: I have a Java Web application, in which I will connect to DB using QT. In app, I have a function that will create a table in schema A then query on this table. For the first time, I execute above procedure without grant privilege to QT so I get the error: "Table or view not exist". So that, I added the SQL to GRANT privilege for QT on schema A and now I have the ORA-0179 as above.

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear.  You can't grant privileges to yourself.  I' ot sure that I understand what problem you are trying to solve?  Why do you want the user `QT` to grant privileges to `QT`?  That doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: I will create a table in schema A by using QT, then I want to grant privileges on the table to QT

Comment: Then user A would need to grant the privilege to QT.  Taking a step back, I'd be very dubious about creating a table at runtime in the first place.  Creating a table at runtime in a different schema is even more questionable.  Unless QT has the `create any table` privilege, the `create` command would need to come from A.  You could potentially create a procedure owned by A that creates the table and grants the privilege and then grant execute access on that procedure to QT.  That would work but it's multiple layers of dubiousness.

Comment: How is `QT` creating a table in the `A` schema?  If it is just issuing the DDL statement, that implies that someone has granted `QT` the `create any table` privilege which would be a terrible security decision.  Unless `QT` has the `select any table` privilege, which would compound the terrible security decisions, then user `A` would need to issue the grants to `QT`.  But you really should not be creating tables at runtime in a web application-- that is a terrible underlying design.